# How to run a script automatically in tcl when a file appears in a directory?

Tags: tcl

I have a script ready in tcl to run but till now i am doing it manually because i have to wait for some file generation to complete.

How to automate this process that if a file appears, tcl script should trigger automatically?

Comment: If you're using linux, there's an inotify package available.

Comment: Yes i am using linux. I will look into what you suggested. Thank you!

Comment: The issue is that i am not allowed to add any external package as such. So if you have any alternate way, please guide me through that.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there are normally zero files in the watched directory, this is an efficient way to poll the directory periodically:

```
proc waitForFiles {directory} {
    set files [glob -directory $directory -nocomplain]
    if {[llength $files] == 0} {
        doSomethingHere
    }
    # check again in 100 milliseconds
    after 100 [list waitForFiles $directory]
}
```

Comment: The after command i learnt from this comment is useful but what if i am expecting a particular file name and if that file appears, i will continue with my next script/command from there. Can i integrate this concept on above mentioned code?

Comment: Change the condition to `if {$expectedFile in $files}` or `if {[file exists [file join $directory $expectedFile]]}`

Comment: Thank you so much Glenn for quick response!! It worked.

Comment: If you know _exactly_ what the file is going to be called, `file exists` or `file readable` are viable choices and are both cheaper than `glob`.